# How to find all enabled email alerts of a list?

Tags: 2010, email, alert

I am using sharepoint 2010. Someone is getting emails after each new item in a list. I see in the email that it is coming from the email alert functionality. I logged in with the account of this user and go to the list, Clicked on "Manage my alerts". I dont see here some enabled email alert, it is empty!  Is there some way to find all enabled email alerts on a list? Not only for the current user.

Comment: Is there a possibility that an event receiver or workflow is triggering email on item added?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked User Alerts under Site Administration? Supposing that you are Site Collection Administrator.

[image]

Comment: Just a note on this to log in on the same site level as the list generating the alerts.

Comment: thanks, I see the email alert listen here. It is created by another user.